# Google sometimes (erratically) shows my blog instead of my website in its results

Tags: seo, wordpress, google-search, blog, search-results

When I go to Google and search on my domain, most of the time I see my website (i.e., `mydomain.com`) in the first page. But sometimes, **instead** of displaying a link to my website, Google shows a link to my blog (i.e., `mydomain.com/blog/`)!

As far as I know, this has only happened with my own computer (not with anyone else's or with any other device), but with several browsers (Firefox and Safari).

Does anyone have an idea about the reason for this weird recurrent change?

In case it helps, my website is running on Magento and my blog is running on WordPress.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As John Conde pointed out, Google results will vary. They are constantly trying to personalize and tailor their search results. Examples:

- Different listings / positions for different users (location, habits, etc).
- Altered listings for mobile users.
- Modification of title tags (when this started to happen, I thought I had inadvertently updated something).
- Site links showing in one search, but not the next.

All in all, it is difficult to figure out what Google is doing in regards to personalized search, especially seeing as they have thousands of different servers, all of which could give back slightly-different listings. Personally, I wouldn't worry about this unless it became too common.

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like a case of personalized search results. Google is returning search results tailored to your search habits. So when you are on your computer, and logged in to Google, you see what Google thinks you want to see based on your search and surfing habits. The rest of the world sees what Google thinks is most relevant for them and they clearly have different habits than you especially when it comes to your own website.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am not far from thinking the same as you, but what surprises me is that it changes very often - like several times per day. And yet, my navigation habits or preferences are way more stable than that - basically, most of the time, when I search "my domain" in Google, it's to access my home page first, and then navigate to any other page within my website, but I always pass by my home page first, so Google should infer that my preference goes to my home page over any other (including my blog), right?

Comment: It's hard to say. Google is constantly updating its rankings so that probably accounts for the inconsistencies you see. As for why they choose one URL over another, it may have more to do with one behavior (search) and another (viewing a page in a browser).